# Self-dual finite-dimensional complex normed spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a complex normed space of dimension 2 or 3 and $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to its dual.  Is $X$ a Hilbert space?

**Remarks:** There are easy counterexamples in the real case, and in higher dimensions one can construct counterexamples from sums of 2-dimensional spaces which are not isometric to their duals.  Similarly a 3-dimensional counterexample can be constructed from a 2-dimensional counterexample.

Comment: Did you try to tensorize your counterexamples i.e. $\C\otimes_\R V$ with the natural extension of the norm and see what happens ? 

Comment: The simplest counterexample is given by the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ norms.  They are of course dual to each other; they are also isometric to each other only in the real 2-dimensional case.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks adding the banach-spaces tag.  I realized later I should have included that one.  I also considered adding the ask-johnson tag, but you had already been here by the time I got to it.

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is, Mark.  Do you know real two dimensional examples other than the obvious ones you mentioned?  Is there a classification of them?  

Comment: Any norm whose unit ball is a regular polygon gives a real two dimensional example.  I don't know if there are others; in particular I don't know whether there is a continuous family of examples, or whether there exist smooth examples.  I discussed the problem with Szarek briefly yesterday and he raised the latter question in particular, but neither of us has given it serious thought.

Comment: That is, I don't know whether there is a continuous family of real 2-dimensional examples, or where there are smooth real 2-dimension examples.  In dimension four one can achieve both with $\ell_p^2 \oplus_2 \ell_q^2$.

Comment: I asked several people this question at a conference last week.  Only one was willing even to state a guess of "not necessarily", but had no counterexample to suggest. 

Comment: Going back to Gérard's comment: without having thought all the way through the details, I'm pretty sure that tensorizing regular polygons with $\mathbb{C}$ in the two obvious ways doesn't produce counterexamples: the sets of extreme points of unit balls seem to have different topology.  In the case of the complex $\ell_1^2$ and $\ell_\infty^2$ norms (which I am sure of), the sets of extreme points consist of two disjoint circles, and a two-dimensional torus, respectively.

Comment: @Mark Did you look at the papers: MR0121625 (22 #12359)
Leichtweiss, Kurt Sur les espaces de Banach auto-adjoints. (French) 1959 Seminaire C. Ehresmann, 1957/58, exp. no. 4 Faculte des Sciences de Paris; and MR0109288 (22 #174)
Leichtweiss,Kurt Selbstadjungierte Banach-Raume. (German)
Math. Z. 71 1959 335–360. They look relevant.

Comment: @Mikhail: No I didn't see those, thanks!

Comment: To answer one question raised in the comments: there are continuously many examples on $\mathbf{R}^2$, such as the hybrid $\ell_p/\ell_q$ norms (for $p,q$ conjugate) defined as the $\ell_p$ norm on the NW/SE quadrants and the $\ell_q$ norm on the NE/SW quadrants. Variants of the constuction give also smooth examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A self-dual norm on $\mathbf{C}^2$ need not be Hilbertian. Here is an example: 
$$ \|(z_1,z_2)\| = \begin{cases} |z_1|+|z_2| & if \ \ \ |z_1| \leq |z_2| \\ 2|z_1| & if \ \ \ |z_1| \geq |z_2|. \end{cases} $$

The dual norm $\|\cdot\|^*$ satisfies $\|(z_1,z_2)\|^*=\frac{1}{2}\|(z_2,z_1)\|$.

Here a picture for $z_1$, $z_2$ real with $\|\cdot\|=1$ in blue and $\|\cdot\|^*=1$ in red.

[image: 1]

Comment: Nice! $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $