# A characterization of Hilbert spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

My question was prompted by an earlier MO by @Daniel:

[***Duality map in strictly convex Banach spaces***](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125765/duality-map-in-strictly-convex-banach-spaces/130226#130226)

I will even use his symbol   $\phi$   below.

Let   $B$   be an arbitrary Banach space. Let   $S := \{x\in B:\|x\|=1\}$   be its unit sphere. Let   $\Gamma := \{f\in B^*: \|f\|=1\}$    be the unit sphere in the dual space $B^*$.

**QUESTION**   Are the following two conditions on $B$ equivalent:

1. $B$   is isometric to a Hilbert space.
2. There exists an isometry   $\phi: \Gamma \rightarrow S$   such that   $\forall_{f\in\Gamma}\ f(\phi(f))=1$.

**?**

The finite-dimensional case is especially basic.

**REMARK 0**   Perhaps similar questions were asked in the past (on MO too?)--please, let me know.

**REMARK 2** The case of   $\mathbb R^2$   and its two dual but isometric norms   $L_\infty\quad L_1$   is interesting. The general question related to the one above is to describe all Banach spaces which are isometric to their dual space. Is there any beside the Hilbert spaces and   $\mathbb R^2$   with the norm(s) just mentioned above?

Comment: Adding a link to the earlier question (specially if you use the notation introduced there) would be useful.

Comment: I have tried to provide a link. The standard HTML way "a href="  didn't work, the link was ignored by the system (didn't show up). I'll learn the OM way one day, I promise myself.

Comment: I am not using any essential prior non-standard notation. I was just giving credit to Daniel by mentioning his usage of $\phi$. I could use equally well most any letter.

Comment: I am sure that all of you have a good time at MO, and feel great. I wish I could say the same. No big deal.

Comment: Maybe this example should be mentionned here: let $X$ be reflexive (so for any finite dimensional space), then $X \oplus_2 X^*$ and its dual are isometric.

Comment: @Yanqi: very nice! You have an entire class. (You may post it below as an answer, to the associated question, so that your construction will be more visible). Thank you, Yanqi.

Comment: Dear Wlodzimierz, you can find formatting tips on this page htpp://mathoverflow.net/editing-help; in particular, a common way to get a link you have to use the syntax [some text](the actual URL). I hope your time on MO is not that bad, because I for one enjoy very much reading your contributions!

Comment: @Mariano: thank you for your kind words, and for your help with MO editing, after which. I have provided the needed link. (BTW, that other page, with the @Daniel's question looks like vandalized, things went wrong there, and it's awkward to look at it. Wiki pages have "history", but I don't know about OM, so I don't know what to think.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is true. Let me show that the existence of $\phi$ implies that the norm of $B^*$ is associated to an inner product. Then it follows easily that the spaces are Hilbert.

It suffices to verify that the norm is an inner product one on every two-dimensional subspace. (Indeed, this property is equivalent to the parallelogram law,  which involves only two-dimensional configurations.)

Let $V$ be a two-dimensional subspace of $B^*$ (equipped with the restriction of the norm of $B^*$) and $V^*$ the dual of $V$ (equipped with the norm dual to this restriction). There is a natural map $\pi:B\to V^*$ dual to the inclusion $V\to B^*$. Namely $\pi(x)(f)=f(x)$ for $x\in B$, $f\in V$. Note that $\pi$ does not increase the norm: $\|\pi(x)\|\le\|x\|$ for all $x\in B$.

Let $D$ be the unit ball of $V$ and $E\subset V$ the maximum-area ellipse contained in $D$ (i.e., the John ellipsoid of $D$). Let $\Sigma$ be the set of points where the boundaries of $D$ and $E$ meet. It is easy to see that $\Sigma$ contains at least two pairs of opposite points. The ellipse $E$ is a unit ball of  a Euclidean norm $\|\cdot\|_E$ on $V$. Since $E\subset D$, we have $\|f\|_E\ge\|f\|$ for all $f\in V$ and equality is attained only if $x$ is proportional to an element of $\Sigma$.

On $V^*$, there is a dual Euclidean norm, denoted by $\|\cdot\|^*_E$. There we have $\|y\|^*_E\le \|y\|$ for all $y\in V^*$. The norm $\|\cdot\|_E$ is associated to an inner product, which defines an isomorphism $I:V\to V^*$ preserving the Euclidean norm.

For every $f\in\Sigma$, we have $\pi(\phi(f))=I(f)$. Indeed, $\|\pi(\phi(f))\|\le\|\phi(f)\|=1$, hence $\|\pi(\phi(f))\|^*_E\le 1$. On the other hand, $\pi(\phi(f))(f)=f(\phi(f))=1$. Since $\|f\|_E=1$, this is possible only for $\pi(\phi(f))=I(f)$.

Now consider two linearly independent vectors $f,g\in\Sigma$ and look at the distance between $f$ and $-g$. Since $\phi$ is an isometry, we have 
$$
\|f+g\|=\|\phi(f)-\phi(-g)\| \ge \|\pi(\phi(f)-\phi(-g))\| .
$$
The r.h.s equals
$$
 \|\pi(\phi(f))-\pi(\phi(-g))\| = \|I(f)-I(-g)\|=\|I(f+g)\|
$$
since $\pi$ and $I$ are linear and $f,-g\in\Sigma$.

Thus $\|I(f+g)\|\le \|f+g\|$ and therefore
$$
\|I(f+g)\|_E^*\le\|I(f+g)\|\le \|f+g\| \le  \|f+g\|_E .
$$
But $I$ preserves the Euclidean norm, so the inequalities turn into equalities. In particular, $\|f+g\|=  \|f+g\|_E$, hence $f+g$ is proportional to an element of $\Sigma$.

Thus we have proved that, for every $f,g\in\Sigma$, the normalized bisector $\frac{f+g}{\|f+g\|}$ also belongs to $\Sigma$. Since $\Sigma$ is a closed subset of an ellipse and contains more than two points, it follows that $\Sigma$ is the whole ellipse. This means that $D=E$, so the norm on $V$ is Euclidean. Q.E.D.

**Remark.** The proof would be much easier (in fact, nearly trivial) if we assumed in advance that $\phi$ is a restriction of an isometry between  $B^*$ and $B$. Then it would be linear by Mazur-Ulam and one could just define the inner product of $f,g\in B^*$ by $2\langle f,g\rangle=g(\phi(f))+f(\phi(g))$.

Comment: Nice, Sergei.  

If some duality map is biLipschitz, then must the Banach space be isomorphic to a Hilbert space?  I have a (possibly false) recollection that this is true but don't see a proof.



Comment: @Bill: this is plausible but I don't know for sure. In finite dimensions, you can differentiate the map at some point and get that a codimension 1 section is within a bounded distance from a Euclidean norm. I don't know how to carry this over to infinite dimensions.


Comment: @Sergei, somehow I missed your answer, I discovered your answer just a moment ago, I am really sorry. I'll carefully read your answer within 24h, and will comment on it (even if I will not get it :-), but at least I will admit it).

Comment: @Sergei, your theorem/proof is very-very nice, you had an idea after an idea.

Answer (score 3):

A related question was asked earlier by Mark Meckes: [Self-dual finite-dimensional complex normed spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123124/self-dual-finite-dimensional-complex-normed-spaces). He pointed out the $l^1$-$l^\infty$ example and noted that it generalizes to unit balls that are regular polygons in the real two-dimensional case. He also told us the $X \oplus_2 X^*$ construction.

I believe the specific question asked by Wlodzimierz has a positive answer, based on a comment I heard Giles Pisier make many years ago --- he said something very similar to this, though I don't remember exactly what. I don't have a reference though.